C# Forms how would I individually select one of the labels and manipulate it before the application has been initialised
Im trying to create a little game similar to word connect as a side project to just get better at coding im pretty new to it al, i created this little UI in visual studio and was wondering if there was a way to manipulate the data of individual labels before the code was actually run or some way to make it so i didnt have to rewrite it all and keep it modular
    using game2.Properties;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace game2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            char[] characters = new char[14];
            string[] newword = new string[3];
            string[] alphabet = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
            int labelcounter = 1;
            int xx = 400;
            int yy = 100;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            List<string> wordList = new List<string>();
            List<char> allCharacters = new List<char>();
            
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();


                StreamReader file = new StreamReader("words.txt");
            {
                string word;
                while ((word = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (word.Length == 5)
                    {
                        wordList.Add(word);
                    }
                }
                file.Close();
            }
            int wordnumchoose = rnd.Next(0, wordList.Count);
        }

           
            private void AddLabel(String msg, int x, int y, String labelName)
            {
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Location = new Point(x, y);
                lbl.Size = new Size(50, 50);
                lbl.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                lbl.Text = msg;
                lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                lbl.Font = new Font("Colonna MT", 12);
                lbl.Name = labelName;
                this.Controls.Add(lbl);
            }

            private void DrawEllipseInt(PaintEventArgs e)
            {

                Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

                int x = 475;
                int y = 350;
                int width = 200;
                int height = 200;

            
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackPen, x, y, width, height);
            }
            protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                if (wordList.Count == 0)
                {
                MessageBox.Show("No 5-letter words found in the word database");
                return;
                }
            base.OnPaint(e);
                int xxx = 500;
                int yyy = 375;
                int j = 1;
                bool vowelAdded = false;
                int[] vowels = { 0,4,8,14,20 };
                int totalLetters = 5;
                int[] selectedletters = new int[totalLetters];

            for (int i = 0; i < totalLetters; i++)
            {
                int letternum;
                if (!vowelAdded && (i == totalLetters - 1 || rnd.Next(0, 2) == 0))
                { 
                        letternum = vowels[rnd.Next(0,vowels.Length)];
                    vowelAdded = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    letternum = rnd.Next(0, alphabet.Length);
                    if (vowelchecker(letternum))
                    {
                        vowelAdded = true;
                    }
                }
                selectedletters[i] = letternum;
                AddLabel(alphabet[letternum], xxx, yyy, "label_" + labelcounter);
                    labelcounter++;
                   
                    if (i <= 1)
                    {
                        xxx = xxx + 100;
                    }
                    if (j >= 2)
                    {
                        yyy = yyy + 75;
                        xxx = 325;
                        j = 0;
                        xxx = xxx + 150;
                    }
                    if (i == 2)
                    {
                        xxx = xxx + 150;
                    }
                    if (i >= 3)
                    {
                        xxx = 400;
                        yyy = 500;
                        xxx = xxx + 150;
                    }
              
                    j++;

            }

            DrawEllipseInt(e);
            HashSet<char> selectedLettersSet = new HashSet<char>();
            foreach (int letterIndex in selectedletters)
            {
                selectedLettersSet.Add(alphabet[letterIndex][0]); 
            }

            List<string> validWords = wordList.Where(word => word.All(letter => selectedLettersSet.Contains(letter))).ToList();

            if (validWords.Count == 0)
            {

                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                int wordnumchoose = rnd.Next(0, validWords.Count);
                newword[i] = validWords[wordnumchoose];
                allCharacters.AddRange(newword[i].ToCharArray());
            }
              characters = allCharacters.ToArray();
        
                while (yy < 400)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
                    {
                        AddLabel(characters[i].ToString(), xx, yy, "label_" + labelcounter);
                        labelcounter++;
                        xx = xx + 50;


                        if (xx > 600)
                        {
                            yy = yy + 100;
                            xx = 400;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                } 
        }
        public static bool vowelchecker(int value)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case 0:
                    return true;

                case 4:
                    return true;

                case 8:
                    return true;

                case 14:
                    return true;

                case 20:
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }


    }
}
    

ive asked chat gpt for some help and have experienced some issues with it just understand with what i want and it told me to create a way name each label and now I'm just wondering on how I would actually manipulate each label to create a string between the letters in the wheel at the bottom to emulate the game word connect
